# Why cannot parse a DateTime?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse a DateTime which I read from a file, the format of the date is:

`19/10/2005 12:00:00 a.m.`

and the code I'm using is:

```
string Fecha = dbRow["FECHA"].ToString().Trim();
DateTime fechamov;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Fecha, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out fechamov)) {
    fechamov = DateTime.Now;
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(pathString, "Corregir nota: " + dbRow["NOTA"].ToString().Trim() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

but before I set the `DateTime.Now` it always gets the value `01/01/0001 12:00:00 a.m.`

I've been trying with different formats, but it just doesn't work, what am I doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that the parser only accepts `AM`, not `a.m.`.

Comment: There is no month 19. Shouldnt it be 10/19/2005?

Comment: @ColinPear Judging by his English and variable names, he's not from the U.S. Most of the world uses the `DDMMYYYY` date format, and his computer culture settings accommodate for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the hour part lowercase

```
"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
```

Uppercase "H" is for 24-hour time.

And i assume that it should be `AM`not `a.m` as Slaks has noted.

Comment: You and @SLaks where right it's with `AM` not `a.m.`, thanks a lot!